# Error in SciChart Stacked Column Chart

Tags: wpf, scichart

http://www.scichart.com/questions/question/error-in-stacked-column-chart-when-one-data-series-has-no-data

Current, I am working an WPF application which using SciChart to draw many charts including a Stacked column chart.
In my case, there are many StackedColumnRenderableSeries in a chart, one of them has less data points then others do and this chart will be rendered incorrectly in a strange way, espcially when I zoomed in and panned it.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

As per this [SciChart Forum answer](http://www.scichart.com/questions/question/error-in-stacked-column-chart-when-one-data-series-has-no-data), Stacked Series must have the same XValues and the same number of data points.

They do suggest using double.NaN for empty points to synchronize the number of points in various stacked series. Or, to temporarily hide empty series by setting BaseRenderableSeries.IsVisible = false.